# Is it possible to update/replace text in a specific slide?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-slides-api, google-slides

Is it possible to update/replace text content in a specific slide?

**Example** - Assuming we have 5 slides in all and we have {product_name} in slide no 2,3,4. But we need to update/replace text {product_name} in slide no 3 only & not for slide no 2,4.

ReplaceAllText is possible but it will replace for all the slides wherever it finds {PRODUCT_NAME}, but we need to update the text for a specific slide only assuming slide no 3 only. I have explored a lot but could not find a way to achieve the same.

```
Snippet for ReplaceAllText (Works for all the slides replace, but we need the same for a specific slide & not for all): -

   requests = [{
      replaceAllText: {
        containsText: {
          text: '{{PRODUCT_NAME}}',
          matchCase: true
        },
        replaceText: PRODUCT_NAME
      }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to replace the text of `{{PRODUCT_NAME}}` in the 3rd slide in a Google Slides.
- You want to achieve this using the batchRequest of Slides API with Google Apps Script.

In this case, I thought that the property of `pageObjectIds` can be used.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const PRODUCT_NAME = "sample value"; // Please set your actual value.
  const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation(); // or SlidesApp.openById("id")
  const pageElementId = s.getSlides()[2].getObjectId(); // pageElementId of 3rd page.
  console.log(pageElementId)
  const resource = {
    requests: [{
      replaceAllText: {
        pageObjectIds: [pageElementId],
        replaceText: PRODUCT_NAME,
        containsText: { matchCase: true, text: "{{PRODUCT_NAME}}" }
      }
    }]
  };
  Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate(resource, s.getId());
}
```

- `const pageElementId = s.getSlides()[2].getObjectId();` returns the page element ID of 3rd page. This is used at `pageObjectIds: [pageElementId]`.

#### References:

- [Method: presentations.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/batchUpdate)
- [ReplaceAllTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#replacealltextrequest)

Comment: Works like a charm! However, it is not retaining the text style such as font-size, font-weight. Is it possible to retain the style of the text?

Comment: @developer55555 Thank you for replying. About the replacing the text, I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I apologize for the inconvenience. About `However, it is not retaining the text style such as font-size, font-weight. Is it possible to retain the style of the text?`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested above script, the text style is not changed. I apologize for this situation. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: In my case the text is bold and font size is 18. Is it possible to retain the font-weight as bold and font-size to 18?

Comment: @developer55555 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `In my case the text is bold and font size is 18. Is it possible to retain the font-weight as bold and font-size to 18?`, when I tested above script, the text style of `the font-weight as bold and font-size to 18` is not changed. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly replicate your situation, can I ask you about the detail flow for replicating it?

Comment: Thanks a lotttttt! Style is retained using your code.

Comment: @developer55555 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Why am I getting error? Even though the slide is editable .

"This operation is not supported for this document". Details: "This operation is not supported for this document">

Comment: @Asha About your question of `Why am I getting error? Even though the slide is editable . "This operation is not supported for this document". Details: "This operation is not supported for this document">`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your comment, I cannot understand your script and your situation. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?